# What happens when Sqoop job will fail after 50% data load?

Tags: sql, hadoop, bigdata, sqoop

I am loading data from Oracle to Hadoop using Sqoop. Unfortunately the Sqoop  job failing after 50% data load.

So I created temp and I started loading data to this temp location. Once it's 100% complete. Then I am copying the data from temp to actual location.

Is there any other way to handle this scenario?

Comment: maybe the errors messages may helps to get more ideas of what happenning.

Comment: Error message is : Connection issue

Comment: Connection on which side ? Try to make smaller data parts.

Comment: If its a connection issue can you try, running it on a screen or tmux, guessing it times out.